# 32-bit physical page table resolution

Tags: windows, memory, x86, kernel

I'm running a 32 bit system in legacy mode on a 64-bit (x86-64 that is) capable architecture. When a new process is created, the kernel has to decide where in physical memory all of the pages needed at the time of instantiation are to be allocated (assuming a single thread this may include several memory regions such as the stack, the heaps etc).

I'm assuming the kernel keeps some sort of dynamic list of the physical RAM frames that are in use, and also a static list of all the regions of physical memory that have been taken up by devices for systems that use memory-mapped IO. Is this correct?

In addition, I also read that a 32-bit Windows system has a physical memory limit of 4GB (probably due to minimum address bus assumptions) so, even though a system may have more than 4 gigabytes of physical memory installed, a 32 bit kernel will only allocate addresses within the 4GB range.

Specific information regarding low-level operating system implementation for specific cases such as this is quite difficult to find online. Can anyone verify these statements and possibly refer me to a source where I could attain more information?

Thanks for your considerations.

Comment: Ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @Hans: Both of the sub-questions are related to the underlying question of the kernel's virtual memory management/allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a new process is created, the kernel has to decide where in physical memory all of the pages needed at the time of instantiation are to be allocated

Why does it have to decide at process creation time?  In fact, it only creates them on-demand - it simply creates the PTEs (i.e. "This address range is valid", but the pages are **not** backed in any way); when the process first starts executing, it immediately **page-faults**.

What is a page fault though? What happens is, first the CPU reads the TLB to see if it has an address <=> frame mapping. When that fails, it walks the PTEs looking for an entry that matches. If no entry is found, or if the entry indicates that the page isn't backed, a *page-fault* is generated. This means, that a CPU exception occurs and the CPU immediately jumps to a predefined address. The first thing the kernel then does is save the CPU Context (i.e. the registers at the location of the fault), then dispatches to the page fault handler.

When the page-fault occurs, Mm (the Memory Manager in NT) will read the mapping in its own data structures (remember that all PE images are memory-mapped files) and determine at that time which physical frame (i.e. 'a real piece of memory') which will be used.

Once the page fault is serviced, the page fault restores the saved CPU context, and jumps back to where it was, and retries the instruction that faulted.

You're correct that a 32-bit OS will only use 4GB of address space (*not* RAM! Don't forget those memory-mapped devices and files!), the processor will operate in 32-bit mode and interpret the PTEs as 32-bit (remember that AMD64 long mode adds an extra level of page tables and extends the address space to 48 bits).

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight. In paragraph two, you stated "if no entry is found..." Does this mean that the page tables are implemented as linked-lists (or some type of non-static data structure)? Or are they just fixed-size (1024 entry) arrays?

Comment: I knew this was the process for instruction memory regions of the virtual address space because the process image in virtual memory is directly mapped onto the disk space. Therefore, a page fault is generated when attempting to access secondary storage. However, I'm still not convinced that this is the case for other regions of memory that are not "pre-mapped" onto any valid location (neither in RAM nor on the disk), such as heap/stack pages. Are you saying that these pages are allocated/paged onto physical memory on access?

Comment: They are implemented as structures which have pointers to other structures, it's not a linked list per-se, but it's also not also a single contiguous block

Comment: I promise, that's how it works! If you allocate 1GB of memory, exactly zero of it gets actually reserved as physical frames. When you page fault is when that virtual address gets assigned a physical frame

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As a follow-up question, how does the memory management unit distinguish between a virtual page that has not been reserved in physical memory and an invalid page (a virtual page that is not within the address space of the process)? Is an invalid page a virtual page for which "no entry is found" as you mentioned in paragraph two?

Comment: There's a bit in the PTE that determines whether the virtual page is valid or not. An invalid page has a PTE that is explicitly not marked as valid, or when it simply doesn't exists

Comment: ahh, I see. For some reason, none of the three PTE structure diagrams included an invalid bit. They all had a "present" bit and various access control bits but no invalid bit.

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I could be misremembering, kd is probably merging the PTE data and some of Mm's internal data

Answer (score 0):

32bit systems can only ever address 4gig directly (2^32 = 4gig). There's [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) hacks, which let the system have more than 4gig of physical ram, but no process can ever have more than 4gig available. As well, even if you have 4gig of ram, you'll never see more than 3.5gig or so actually available - some is reserved for memory mapping hardware devices, such as your video ram.

For one method of dealing with the physical-virtual memory mapping, look at [TLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question was not so much about how the paging mechanism actually works but how it is established and managed. The TLB is simply a cache that containing PTEs and is used to speed up the virtual address translation process. Maybe I'm missing something on the Wikipedia TLB page you linked, but I don't think it says anything about how the system kernel manages the allocation of the page tables/directories.